# Sanity Check: Is it possible to proxy between an HLS(m3u8) video stream and an angularjs app (ui)?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, video, video-streaming, spring-webflux

I need to create a Spring Boot WebFlux rest web service to act as a proxy between an angularjs app that shows a video stream and an endpoint at dacast.com that delivers m3u8 playlist-based content.

At this time, there is a video component in the angular app that takes the following uri and presents the content to the user.  I plan to create a reactive webflux rest service, but am at a loss as to how to implement this proxy.  There are a lot of posts online about viewing the HLS feed in HTML, but nothing about how to proxy between the stream and a consumer of it.

https://dcunilive11-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dlive_1@xxxxxx/master.m3u8

I believe that I need to download the master.m3u8 file, which will contain https endpoints that I can download as a Flux stream and pass along to the angular app.  Does this make sense?  I'd appreciate your help and tips...

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The m3u8 file is a text file which contains some info about the video and links to the media streams as you say.

The simplest way for the angular app to play the video would be just to provide the link to the original m3u8 file to it directly, but I am guessing  it can't reach that link for some reason in your use case.

Assuming this is correct, it sounds like your web service just needs to act as a proxy for the m3u8 file link and the media streams.

There are some instructions in the online Spring documentation for this - e.g.: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/1.0.x/multi/multi__building_a_gateway_using_spring_mvc.html

One thing that may be causing some confusion is that the HLS media streams are actually transferred between the client and the server as a series of client requests and server responses, i.e. similar to regular HTTP request/responses. They are not constantly streaming, i.e. something that that you might use a websocket to read.

Comment: Thank you for the great response, Mick!  I didn't think about spinning up a Spring Gateway (reactive) and use its proxying features!  I will give it a whirl and report back.